# connect to local WordpressDB using XML-RPC

Tags: python, xml, wordpress, localhost, xml-rpc

im trying to connect to my local website, which i setup using wampserver, i can
connect to it via browser.
However, when i try to connect to it via python:

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.taxonomies import *
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import *
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.users import *
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods import *

wp_site = Client("http://localhost/testwp/", "my wp username", "my wp password")
```

i get the error:

```
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 3, column 29
```

is it even possible to connect to a local server using xml-rpc, or what am i doing wrong?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to connect to a local wp server using `python-wordpress-xmlrpc` library.
According to official docs in order to do so, we need to access **xmlrpc.php** file in the root wp directory while setting up the connection. In the snippet provided in the original question consider changing the last line to:
`wp_site = Client("http://localhost/testwp/xmlrpc.php", "my wp username", "my wp password")`.

Possible sample code to get User info might look like so:

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.taxonomies import *
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import *
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.users import *
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods import *

wp_site = Client("http://localhost/testwp/xmlrpc.php", "my_wp_username", "my_wp_password")
user_info = wp_site.call(GetUserInfo())
print(user_info)
```

Comment: thanks for the effort :) this is 8 months old, i don't even remember the situation

Comment: @Villian79 Nope, it's not working.